# How to solve the equation given below

Tags: python, matlab

I have difficulty understanding how to go about or solve this question. Can someone please explain how do i solve the difference equation and plot the same.

> y(n) − 2.56y(n − 1) + 2.22y(n − 2) − 0.65y(n − 3) = x(n) + x(n − 3)
> Compute the first four cycles of the output by directly implementing the above difference equation.
> Given x(n) is a sinusoid of frequency 500hz sampled at 6000hz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Plotting the Output of a System Modelled by a Difference Equation

Not sure if you have any constraints on using built-in functions. To plot the output of a system described by a difference equation the `filter()` function can be used. The filter function takes in a few parameters as follows:

### Function Call:

```
y = filter(Numerator,Denominator,x);
```

`x` → Input of the system. 
`y` → Output of the system. 
`Numerator` → The output coefficients (y-coefficients).
`Denominator` → The input coefficients (x-coefficients).

---

[image: Plotting Output of Difference Equation]

```
%Sinusoid frequency -> 500Hz%
f = 500;
Sinusoid_Period = 1/f;

%Sampling frequency -> 6000Hz%
Sampling_Frequency = 6000;
Sampling_Period = 1/Sampling_Frequency;

Start_Time = 0;
Number_Of_Cycles = 4;
Number_Of_Samples_Per_Period = Sinusoid_Period/Sampling_Period;
End_Time = Sampling_Period*Number_Of_Cycles*Number_Of_Samples_Per_Period;
t = (Start_Time: Sampling_Period: End_Time);

Sinusoid = @(t) sin(2*pi*f*t);
x = Sinusoid(t);
n = (0: length(x)-1);
subplot(2,1,1); stem(n,x); 
title("x[n] 500Hz Input Sinusoid Sampled at 6000Hz");
xlabel("Sample [n]"); ylabel("Magnitude");
xlim([0 length(x)]);


Numerator = [1 -2.56 2.22 -0.65]; %Output y coefficients%
Denominator = [1 0 0 1]; %Input x coefficients%
y = filter(Numerator,Denominator,x);
subplot(2,1,2); stem(n,y);
title("y[n] Output Signal From Difference Equation");
xlabel("Sample [n]"); ylabel("Magnitude");
xlim([0 length(x)]);
```

Comment: What would be the process if there was a constraint of not using any functions? Thank you

Comment: Would take some messy for loops or an anonymous function with the inputs zero padded.